# neural network to implement binary counting

Tags: machine-learning, binary, neural-network

Recently I've implemented feed-forward multiplayer neural network and it successfully perform 3bit binary counting. Train-set includes all values from 0 0 0 to 1 1 1. (exhausted case)

However, if I train network only for fewer values, say only from 0 to 4,
it doesn't work well for the inputs that were missing from learning set (5,6,7)

So My question is should network also be able to calculate correct output for the inputs that are not included in the train set?  This is confusing, as if you must provide learning set for all possible inputs what's the benefit behind neural networks?